# Group data by key with the groupBy operator rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

"rxjs": "7.8.0",

I get the following Observable from api.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": 1693229400000,
        "name": "event name",
        "impact": "Low",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date": 1693229400000,
        "name": "event name",
        "impact": "Low",
    },    
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": 1693229400000,
        "name": "event name",
        "impact": "Middle",
    }
]
```

I want to group response by impact field. But my solution returns nothing. Console.log is also not shown.

```
events$ = this.onSubmit.pipe(
    switchMap((dateRange) => this.eventService.getEvents())
  ).pipe(
    mergeMap(res => res),
    groupBy(i => i.impact),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
  ).subscribe(res => console.log('RESULT', res));
```

Comment: It seems that your using **pipe()** operators twice instead of a single time, try by removing the second pipe and encapsulate everything with the first one before the susbscribe

Comment: How would you do that ? Does the `onSubmit` observable complete ??

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler you are right. The reason was that onSubmit never completed. Thanks.